# Generate number in form (Year/Month/Type/Number) - Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, date

I need add variable to form that will return number.

My current code in controller.

```
    /*Generate number*/
    $query = Certificate::latest()->first(); //get last query
    $ex = explode('/', $query->number); //explode last number from DB
    $type = strtoupper(Request::segment(3)); //get type from url

    if(empty($query->number)) {
        $number = '1';
        $nextNumber = date('Y/m').'/'.$type.'/'.$number;
    } else {
        $number = $ex[3]+1;
        $nextNumber = date('Y/m').'/'.$type.'/'.$number;
    }
```

My current code in template.

```
{!! Form::text('number', $nextNumber, ['class'=>'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

My code return number YEAR/MONTH/TYPE/NUMBER - [Screenshot in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gy9V.jpg)

*Now it does not work as it should*

- 2018/07/WK/6
- 2018/07/WK/7
- 2018/07/S/8
- 2018/07/WK/9
- 2018/07/WK/10
- 2018/07/S/11
- 2018/07/PT/12 ... 13,14,15,16,17,18 ++ [...]

I need reset number for TYPE and new month.

*Please see an example of an action:*

- 2018/07/WK/1
- 2018/07/WK/2
- 2018/07/S/1
- 2018/07/WK/3
- 2018/07/WK/4
- 2018/07/S/2
- 2018/07/PT/1

*Example in the new month:*

- 2018/08/WK/1
- 2018/08/S/1
- 2018/08/PT/1
- 2018/08/WK/2
- 2018/08/WK/3
- 2018/08/S/2
- 2018/08/PT/2

I will be very grateful if someone leads me to a solution.

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation i think you have to add condition when you get data from database.

```
$type = strtoupper(Request::segment(3)); //get type from url
$query = Certificate::where('number', 'LIKE', '%/'.$type.'/%')
              ->latest()->first(); //get last query
$ex = explode('/', $query->number); //explode last number from DB
```

This will return last number from DB on specified $type.

If it is possible, i recommend save type in another column of database table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not helpful for me :(

This is my database - screenshot here

I want each number to reset for the type and the new month.

Many thanks for help !

Comment: Maybe i explained wrong or did not get your question. I mean first u need to get latest record with specified type from database. Then u extract number from this record and increment number. Is that right?

Comment: I thought about it. Your answer has been helpful. Thank you !